# How do I modify Chromium's default data directory?

Tags: windows-7, browser, user-profiles, chromium

I believe I somehow messed up my user profile directories with my Chromium installation. Every time I launch Chromium, it tells me:

```
Chromium cannot read and write to its data directory:

C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Chromium\User Data
```

It lets me choose another directory, and if I choose `C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Chromium\`, then it launches fine. I can also add the command line argument `--user-data-dir` to point to the directory.

However, how can I modify the default (currently `C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Chromium\User Data`) data directory to change it to the correct one? I don't only get this error when opening Chromium, but also when an application tries open my default browser.

Comment: Try creating a directory named "[Default](http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory)" under `C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Chromium\User Data` and point to it if asked by the browser. See if that works (and sticks).

Comment: That directory already exists, when I tried using that directory it just created a new profile at `C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Chromium\User Data\Default\Default`. The directory that I believe I currently use is at `C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Chromium\Default`.

Comment: If you're trying to use a whole new user data dir, you might prefer to just delete (or rename) the current one and then Chromium should create it when you start it up.

Comment: I'm not trying to create a new data directory, but to edit the default profile it tries to use when it starts up, and change it to my current profile (`C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Chromium\Default`).

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by doing the following:

- Deleted `C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Chromium\User Data`, since there was no real profiles in it anyway.
- Started Chromium. It created a new profile at `C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Chromium\User Data\Default`, without any bother. Then closed Chromium.
- Move and merge my real profile (`C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Chromium\Default`) in to the newly created profile, then start Chromium. It detects it and runs without any hassle.